# Can't map file memory in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

The windows server 2003 box hosting our MongoDB instance ran out of disk space, and Mongo started generating the error:

**Can't map file memory.**

After adding additional disk space to the server and restarting the MongoDB windows service, any operation against the database still generates the "Can't map file memory" error. I tried doing a repair even and it gives the same error:

**> db.repairDatabase();
{
        "assertion" : "can't map file memory",
        "assertionCode" : 10085,
        "errmsg" : "db assertion failure",
        "ok" : 0
}**

Any idea what I can do to get my database operational again??

Comment: You do not need to delete the lock file when repairing your database.  I was having a similar issue when our hosting provider shut down a MongoDB server without warning.  The replica set would not start up correctly, and `rs.initiate()` was throwing the above exception.  I shutdown the server using `db.shutdownServer()` and started `mongod` with the `--repair` flag.  After completing the database was able to be brought up again.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stopping the service, deleting the lock file, and then doing a mongod --repair worked, even though db.repairDatabase did not.

Comment: Turns out this didn't work as well as I expected. Even though Mongo is running again without errors, it's now using up 90% of the cpu...

Answer (score 6):

The answer from Justin worked for me.

Here are some more detailed instructions for Ubuntu:

```
Stop Mongo Service: sudo service mongodb stop
Delete Lock File: sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
Repair the DB: sudo mongod --repair --dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb
Restart the Mongo Service: sudo service mongodb start
```

Hope that helps someone.

(edited - note that mongodb is the service name, but mongod is the correct command for repairing)

Comment: You shouldn't shut down MongoDB that way.  The best way of doing this would be to get into the mongo shell inside the admin db (`mongo admin`), then shut down the server with this command: `db.shutdownServer()`  This will produce a clean shutdown without any problems from Mongo.